# Get parts of this array to print out in php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Here is the code I have,

```
$menu_name = 'featured-page'; // Name of Custom Navagation in the back end

if ( ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $menu_name ] )) {
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
    $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);
}

foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
  $numbers[] = get_post_meta( $menu_item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
}

var_dump($numbers) ;
```

---

```
var_dump($numbers) ;
```

will display this

array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(1) "9" [2]=> string(1) "8" }

I need to print out this

11,9,8

How can this be done?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/implode. Honestly... if you can't figure out to get a value(s) out of an array, you really really should learn basic programming and basic PHP.

Comment: @MarcB That is what I am doing. . . For some reason that has seemed to slip my mind, I thought this was a place to ask questions and get a better understand of what is going on . . .

I am guessing that you also gave a hint and say I should look in to implode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use implode

```
echo implode(',', $numbers);
```

Comment: Thanks Jibran Khan!  This did just the trick, and has got me a big step closer to getting my final goal done.  

I will be doing this 

'$nubers_needed = implode(',', $numbers);'

And making it so I can insert them in the this array ''post__in' => array(8,9,11),'

Again, Think you very much!